# Why doesn't PrintWriter work with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, sleep

PrintWriter works (it writes to the external file) until I add the line that says `Thread.sleep(100);`. Then the code still compiles just fine, and it continues writing to the console, but it won't print to the external file. But I can't figure out why?

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RecordMouse {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    String line = "";

    // string for filename
    String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + "out.txt";
    // create file
    File file = new File(filename);
    // create writer
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    try
    {
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);

        while(true){
            //Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " hi \n");
            printWriter.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " hi");
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( printWriter != null ) 
        {
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it do when it works? What does it do when it doesn't work?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? `Thread.sleep()` throws `InterruptedException`, and your code is not catching that type of exception.

Comment: It's in the title. I'll elaborate in the post.

Comment: @Mike I don't see why that should be a problem. The `main` method declares that it throws `InterruptedException`.

Comment: I want to write every .1 seconds, but sleep is causing it to not write.

Comment: You say that when adding the sleep it does not print to the external file, but does it still print to the console? That is, do you still see the results of `System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " hi \n");`?

Comment: @Aaron yes it still prints to the console.

Comment: What if you were to comment out the `while(true)` so that it is not in a loop and instead happens only 1 time; does it write to the file then after sleeping?

Comment: The reason for my previous question about removing the loop is related to file flushing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference `sleep` makes in your case is that it slows down frequency of writes and and it will take a while until the writes get flushed into the file. By removing the `sleep` you are causing the write flush to happen much more earlier. Change the sleep time into something smaller (like 5 instead of 100) or wait a little longer and see that the file gets written over.

Comment: Or add a flush call for each loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I didn't understand is the difference between stream and buffer. Or that the buffer would eventually dump. Changing the sleep time is not desirable because I don't want that much data, but I was able to add `printWriter.flush();` to the loop as @StephenC suggested to flush the buffered data into the file.